# GTK+ 3 CSS: How to specify text alignment for a label?

Tags: css, gtk

I'm having hard time finding GTK+ 3.4 CSS reference and figuring out what properties can be set through CSS and how. I'm working with GTK+ 3.4 (debian wheezy).

General Q: is there a GTK+ (3.4) CSS reference with all accepted properties (per widget)?

Specific: Is it possible (how) to specify text alignment for the label within GtkButton?
I.e. is there a way to set xalign and yalign through CSS?

I've tried

```
.mybutton * { text-align: center; }
```

and similar, but I get "'text-align' is not a valid property name"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [GtkCssProvider (includes a supported, almost complete list of properties)](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html) regarding what is supported and what is not.

Comment: Thank you - i know that page by heart (almost) :)

Comment: My difficulties with Gtk+ 3 and CSS obviously come from compatibility issues between diverse g* libraries and system set up (themes, engines, ...), glade; then GtkBuilder not setting widget names (any more) ...

Comment: Can you given a example what exactly goes wrong? I will have a look next weekend then CodeDiver(TM).

Comment: It's not simple. E.g.: glade 3.14 (debian jessie/testing) generates and allows to enter a widget (or object) name and puts it into the id= attribute. Gtk 3.4 loads this name as Buildable (!) name, but not as widget name. Hence, name based selectors won't work. gtkmm has Buildable::get_name() which is hidden by Widget::get_name(), so I need to ((Gtk::Buildable *) widget)->get_name() to get it ...

Comment: Specific: it seems that text alignment / justification of GtkLabel can not be set through CSS (yet).

Comment: Sorry for digging this out but with GTK4 at least it looks like `text-align: right` within CSS works to align text to the right of a label.